# Function expected error while pressing download button

Tags: javascript, angular, microsoft-edge

When I am pressing the download button on my website in Microsoft Edge, I am getting the "Function expected" error.

```js
download() {
    this.element = document.getElementById("img") as HTMLElement;
    let dataurl = this.element.innerHTML;
    let myRegexp = /(?:^|\s)src=(.*?)(?:\s|$)/g;
    let match = myRegexp.exec(dataurl);
    let match1 = match[1].replace('"></div>', '');

    this.ImageURL = match1;
    let block = this.ImageURL.split(";");
    let contentType = block[0].split(":")[1];
    let realData = block[1].split(",")[1];
    let file = this.dataURLtoFile(this.ImageURL, 'QRCode.png');
}

  dataURLtoFile(dataurl, filename) {
    var arr = dataurl.split(','), mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
      bstr = atob(arr[1]), n = bstr.length, u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
    while (n--) {
      u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
    }
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    var blob = new Blob([new File([u8arr], filename, { type: mime })], { type: 'mime' }),
      url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = `QRCode.png`;
    a.click();
    setTimeout(function () {
      document.body.removeChild(a);
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }, 100);
    return new File([u8arr], filename, { type: mime });
}
```

The file should download:

Here is the error:

> [object Error]: {description: "Function expected", message: "Function
>   expected", number: -2146823286, stack: "TypeError: Function expected
>   at n.prototype.dataURLtoFile
>   (http://instacei.com/1.bb25259c0233e7528077.js:1:237067) at
>   n.prototype.download
>   (http://instacei.com/1.bb25259c0233e7528077.js:1:236764) at Anonymous
>   function (http://instacei.com/1.bb25259c0233e7528077.js:1:155143) at
>   handleEvent
>   (http://instacei.com/main.1533bf301f026a959db3.js:1:117135) at
>   handleEvent
>   (http://instacei.com/main.1533bf301f026a959db3.js:1:138938) at Lr
>   (http://instacei.com/main.1533bf301f026a959db3.js:1:87225) at
>   Anonymous function
>   (http://instacei.com/main.1533bf301f026a959db3.js:1:93361) at
>   Anonymous function
>   (http://instacei.com/main.1533bf301f026a959db3.js:1:284082) at
>   e.prototype.invokeTask
>   (http://instacei.com/polyfills.481858ef51fe27531859.js:1:7664) at
>   onInvokeTask
>   (http://instacei.com/main.1533bf301f026a959db3.js:1:55627)"}

Comment: Which line of code you get the error ?

Comment: and include the exact error message too please.

Comment: The file is created at runtime.

Comment: Either you attempted to invoke one of the Function prototype methods on an object that was not a Function object, or you used an object in a function call context. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/misc/function-expected